# "Unresolved External Symbol" errors when creating object in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm a pretty seasoned programmer but I'm just now diving into C++ and it's... well... more difficult than PHP and Python. I keep having unresolved external errors when trying to create an object from some classes. It's broken up into multiple headers and files but here is a basic idea from one of my classes:

**die.h:**

```
#ifndef DIE_H
#define DIE_H

using namespace std;

class Die {
 public: 
  int throwDie();
  Die();
};

#endif
```

**die.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Die.h"

using namespace std;

int Die::throwDie() 
{
 return 0;
}
```

**sixsidedie.h**

```
#ifndef SIXSIDEDIE_H
#define SIXSIDEDIE_H

#include "Die.h"

using namespace std;

class SixSideDie : public Die
{
 public:
  SixSideDie();
  int throwDie();

 private: 
         int randNumber;
};

#endif
```

**sixsidedie.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "Die.h"
#include "SixSideDie.h"

using namespace std;

const int SIX_SIDE = 6;

int SixSideDie::throwDie()
{
 srand((unsigned int)time(0));
 SixSideDie::randNumber = rand() % SIX_SIDE + 1;
 return SixSideDie::randNumber;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Die.h"
#include "SixSideDie.h"
#include "TenSideDie.h"
#include "TwentySideDie.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
 Die* myDice[3];
 myDice[0] = new SixSideDie();
 myDice[1] = new TenSideDie();
 myDice[2] = new TwentySideDie();

 myDice[0]->throwDie();
 myDice[1]->throwDie();
 myDice[2]->throwDie();

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

It keeps telling me that each object I create directly above is an unresolved external symbol and I just don't know why. Any thoughts!?

Comment: Sorry about the #includes up top. Apparently it filtered those out but I think they are inconsequential anyways.

Comment: Got it! Forgot to make constructors. Silly me. Thanks for the quick help guys you're simply the best. Hope I can contribute myself soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared a constructor for `Die` but never defined it.

Also, you almost certainly want `throwDie` to be virtual if you intend to override its behavior in derived classes, and you should never use `using namespace std;` in a header file (and many people, including me, would argue that you shouldn't use it at file-scope at all).

Comment: You're right about the virtual! That's actually the next step in the lab but I have to get the program to compile first. I'll try that and report back. Inheritance is still a bit mind-boggling to me! :D

Comment: Well you were all 100% correct but I'll give you props on the namespace tip. I'm sure that would have cost me some points tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define your constructor in your cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

Its good practice to define the constructors of the classes. Check this out:

```
#ifndef DIE_H
#define DIE_H

using namespace std;

class Die {
 public: 
  int throwDie();
  Die() { };  // can you spot the difference here?
};

#endif
```

Comment: Or just don't explicitly declare a constructor if you don't need to.

Comment: Just a heads-up:  If you use the @name, it has to be the first characters of the user's name, otherwise the user won't get a notification.